# What is a charter airline, and what are the risks of flying with one?

Tags: air-travel, charter

I am travelling from Burgas to Munich and the only direct flight appears to be with "Bulgarian Air Charter":

[image]

Apparently this is a "charter airline". I cannot find any information on the reliability of the airline itself, or on the flight number `H6 3919`. What are the risks associated with taking this flight over a "regular" flight such as Lufthansa `LH 1707` from Sofia to Munich?

Comment: Bulgarian Air Charter [has renamed itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Air_Charter_(Bulgarian_airline)) European Air Charter.

Comment: Typically, you cannot book a seat on a charter flight directly from the operator. Instead, the charterer (say a tour operator like TUI) sells tickets as part of a package. But it seems this one does show up in Kiwi's results so I don't know. Incidentally, you can also charter a plane from most airlines operating scheduled flights, including legacy airlines like [Lufthansa](https://www.lufthansa.com/br/en/exclusive-charter).